# Request data from backend to show it in extension UI

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I have a class with needed requests that I use for my app.

So let's say that I need movies list from server:

```
[[MyApiClass sharedInstance] getMovies];
```

So it return for me JSON with movies. How can I get this list, for my share extension?

The problem that the MyApiClass is not in the compiled resources of extension target.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem that the MyApiClass is not in the compiled resources of extension target.

Well in that case, select `MyApiClass` and in the file inspector (right sidebar first tab), add the class to your extension target :-)

Comment: yep it's simple) but my MyApiClass contains other files I think at least about 50 data models classes that I need to include and find as well

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander then include all of them! You can't do without :/

Comment: yep, I can add it but here is a problem with extensions I've described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551648/ios-8-extension-dependencies-issues-importing-one-project-file-to-extension-vie)